# Airlfow API : testing tasks with parameters

Tags: python, airflow, pytest, etl

I can't figure out how to use pytest to test a dag task waiting for xcom_arg.

I created the following DAG using the new airflow API syntax :

```py
 
@dag(...)
def transfer_files():

  @task()
  def retrieve_existing_files():
    existing = []

    for elem in os.listdir("./backup"):
      existing.append(elem)
    return existing

  @task()
  def get_new_file_to_sync(existing: list[str]):
    new_files = []

    for elem in os.listdir("./prod"):
      if not elem in existing:
        new_files.append(elem)
    return new_files

  r = retrieve_existing_files()
  get_new_file_to_sync(r)
```

Now I want to perform unit testing on the `get_new_file_to_sync` task. I wrote the following test :

```py
def test_get_new_elan_list():
    mocked_existing = ["a.out", "b.out"]

    dag_bag = DagBag(include_examples=False)
    dag = dag_bag.get_dag("transfer_files")

    task = dag.get_task("get_new_file_to_sync")
    result = task.execute({}, mocked_existing)

    print(result)
```

The test fails because `task.execute` is waiting for 2 parameters but 3 were given.

My issue is that I don't have any clue of how to proceed in order to test my tasks waiting for arguments with a mocked custom argument.

Thanks for your insights

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find a way to unit test airflow tasks declared using the new [airflow API](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/tutorial_taskflow_api.html).

Here is a test case for the task `get_new_file_to_sync` contained in the DAG `transfer_files` declared in the question :

```py
def test_get_new_file_to_synct():
    mocked_existing = ["a.out", "b.out"]
    
    # Asking airflow to load the dags in its home folder
    dag_bag = DagBag(include_examples=False)

    # Retrieving the dag to test
    dag = dag_bag.get_dag("transfer_files")
    
    # Retrieving the task to test
    task = dag.get_task("get_new_file_to_sync")

    # extracting the function to test from the task
    function_to_unit_test = task.python_callable
    
    # Calling the function normally
    results = function_to_unit_test(mocked_existing)

    assert len(results) == 10
```

This allows bypassing all the airflow mechanics triggered before calling the actual code you have written for your task. Thus, you can focus on writing tests for the code you have written for your task.

Answer (score 0):

For testing such a task, I believe you'll need to use `mocking` from pytest.

Let's take this user defined operator for an example:

```
class MovielensPopularityOperator(BaseOperator):
   def __init__(self, conn_id, start_date, end_date, min_ratings=4, top_n=5, **kwargs):
       super().__init__(**kwargs)
       self._conn_id = conn_id
       self._start_date = start_date
       self._end_date = end_date
       self._min_ratings = min_ratings
       self._top_n = top_n

   def execute(self, context):
       with MovielensHook(self._conn_id) as hook:
           ratings = hook.get_ratings(start_date=self._start_date, end_date=self._end_date)

           rating_sums = defaultdict(Counter)
       for rating in ratings:
           rating_sums[rating["movieId"]].update(count=1, rating=rating["rating"])

       averages = {
           movie_id: (rating_counter["rating"] / rating_counter["count"], rating_counter["count"])
           for movie_id, rating_counter in rating_sums.items()
           if rating_counter["count"] >= self._min_ratings
       }
       return sorted(averages.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)[: self._top_n]
```

And a test written just like the one you did:

```
def test_movielenspopularityoperator():
    task = MovielensPopularityOperator(
        task_id="test_id",
        start_date="2015-01-01",
        end_date="2015-01-03",
        top_n=5,
    )
    result = task.execute(context={})
    assert len(result) == 5
```

Running this test fail as:

```
=============================== FAILURES ===============================
___________________ test_movielenspopularityoperator ___________________
mocker = <pytest_mock.plugin.MockFixture object at 0x10fb2ea90>
def test_movielenspopularityoperator(mocker: MockFixture):
task = MovielensPopularityOperator(
➥
 >
 task_id="test_id", start_date="2015-01-01", end_date="2015-01-
03", top_n=5
)
➥
 E
 TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument:
'conn_id'
tests/dags/chapter9/custom/test_operators.py:30: TypeError
========================== 1 failed in 0.10s ==========================
```

> The test failed because we’re missing the required argument conn_id, which points to the connection ID in the metastore. But how do you provide this in a test? Tests should be isolated from each other; they should not be able to influence the results of other tests, so a database shared between tests is not an ideal situation. In this case, mocking comes to the rescue.

> Mocking is “faking” certain operations or objects. For example, the call to a database that is expected to exist in a production setting but not while testing could be faked, or mocked, by telling Python to return a certain value instead of making the actual call to the (nonexistent during testing) database. This allows you to develop and run tests without requiring a connection to external systems. It requires insight into the internals of whatever it is you’re testing, and thus sometimes requires you to dive into third-party code.

After installing pytest-mock in your enviroment:

```
pip install pytest-mock
```

Here is the test written where mocking is used:

```
def test_movielenspopularityoperator(mocker):
   mocker.patch.object(
       MovielensHook,
       "get_connection",
       return_value=Connection(conn_id="test", login="airflow", password="airflow"),
   )
   task = MovielensPopularityOperator(
       task_id="test_id",
       conn_id="test",
       start_date="2015-01-01",
       end_date="2015-01-03",
       top_n=5,
   )
   result = task.execute(context=None)
   assert len(result) == 5
```

Now, hopefully this will give you an idea about how to write your tests for Airflow Tasks.

For more about mocking and unit tests, you can check [here](https://blogs.sap.com/2022/02/16/how-to-write-independent-unit-test-with-pytest-and-mock-techniques/) and [here.](https://changhsinlee.com/pytest-mock/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My trouble here is more about "what should I mock ?". As creating dag with decorator abstract the xcom communication between two tasks I have trouble finding what I should mock to inject the data I need for my test as the parameter of my airflow task.

Comment: Oh, you are right. I guess writing tests is also a bit different (than just writing them for single Operators) in the Taskflow API, with the first tasks return. I'll let you know I find anything.